# Send sender name with email SendGrid - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid

I am using `SendGrid` to send emails from my application. I want to send `sender name` along with `sender email` e.g.  `from: 'Maxcreet <contact@maxcreet.com>'`

It is working fine using `Letter Opener` and `MailTrap` but SendGrid only show sender email.

Here is my SendGrid functionto send emails.

```
def deliver!(mail)
  email.from = SendGrid::Email.new(email: mail[:from].addrs.first.address)
  email.subject = mail.subject
  email.add_personalization(build_personalization(mail))
  build_content(mail)
  send!(email)
end
```

I have checked `mail[:from]` values using `puts` it gives following values:

```
puts mail[:from]                      => Maxcreet <support@maxcreet.com>
puts mail[:from].addrs                => Maxcreet <support@maxcreet.com>
puts mail[:from].addrs.first          => Maxcreet <support@maxcreet.com>
puts mail[:from].addrs.first.address  => support@maxcreet.com
```

Above 3 seems OK for me but when I use any of them in

```
email.from = SendGrid::Email.new(email: mail[:from].addrs.first.address)
```

It does not sent my email and even I do not find my email in sendgrid dashboard.

Following [this](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/issues/152) also tried `email.fromname` but this even did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SendGrid's ruby API has this option with name `name` and not `fromname`.

So the following should solve your problem.

```
email.from = SendGrid::Email.new(
  email: mail[:from].addrs.first.address, 
  name:  mail[:from].addrs.first.name
)
```

I concluded this by trying it from [this doc](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/api_v3.html).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're mixing gems or objects. `SendGrid::Email.new` just needs a `from` String, and might support a `name` String. You're extracting the address from your `mail[:from]` Hash with `mail[:from].addrs.first.address`, but you need to provide the name as a distinct Key.

In the [SendGrid Ruby gem](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-ruby/blob/master/examples/helpers/mail/example.rb#L26) 'kitchen sink" example, they don't show a `name` on the From argument, but they do on the `personalization`.

Try: `email.from = SendGrid::Email.new(email: 'support@maxcreet.com', name: 'Maxcreet'))`

or dynamically: `email.from = SendGrid::Email.new(email: mail[:from].addrs.first.address, name: mail[:from].addrs.first.name))`

if your `mail` Object recognizes that Key.

Otherwise, you'll need to look at your `mail` gem's documentation for how to extract a Friendly/Display Name from that `mail[:from].addrs` Object.